# "..." in function prototype

Tags: c++, syntax

I saw someone's C++ code has function declaration like below:

```
void information_log( const char* fmt , ...)
```

or catch block like

```
catch(...)
{
}
```

What does "..." mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ellipsis `...`, in a function prototype, is used to denote the function as variadic. That is, it enables a variable number of arguments to be passed into the function. In this form, a function must define some way for the user to specify exactly how many arguments they presented, since the variadic library functions in C++ can't determine this information dynamically.

For example, the stdio function `printf` is one such function with the prototype:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Presumably, from the similarities between the two prototypes, the `information_log` function you describe is designed to mirror much of `printf`'s functionality and perhaps even internally uses `printf`, or one of its cousins.

The following is an example of how to implement a variadic function:

```
// cstdarg provides access to the arguments passed to the ellipsis
#include <cstdarg> // or (#include <stdarg.h>)
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

// Concatenates as many strings as are present
void concatenate(char ** out, int num_str, ...)
{
    // Store where the arguments are in memory
    va_list args;

    // Find the first variadic argument, relative to the last named argument
    va_start(args, num_str);

    int out_len = 0;
    int * lengths = new int[num_str];
    char ** strings = new char*[num_str];

    // Extract the strings from the variadic argument list
    for(int i = 0; i < num_str; i++)
    {
        // Specify the position in the argument list and the type
        // Note: You must know the type, stdarg can't detect it for you
        strings[i] = va_arg(args, char *);
        lengths[i] = strlen(strings[i]);
        out_len += lengths[i];
    }

    // Concatenate the strings
    int dest_cursor = 0;
    (*out) = new char[out_len + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_str; i++)
    {
        strncpy( (*out) + dest_cursor, strings[i], lengths[i]);
        dest_cursor += lengths[i];
    }
    (*out)[dest_cursor] = '\0';

    // Clean up
    delete [] strings;
    delete [] lengths;
    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    char * output = NULL;

    // Call our function and print the result
    concatenate(&output, 5, "The ", "quick", " brown ", "fox ", "jumps!\n");
    printf("%s", output);

    delete [] output;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does printf determine the number of provided arguments dynamically then?

Comment: @f0ster The number of arguments are specified in the first c-string parameter `printf`. The function will parse the formatting string and each time it finds a token starting with % it will treat it as special (i.e. read the next parameter from the variadic list). In my code example you'll see I use a call to `printf("%s", output);`, the `%s` indicates to the function to expect a string parameter. Parameters correspond 1-to-1 from left to right again the tokens in the formatting string. Hope this clears that up.

Answer (score 7):

Those are really two separate questions here, just using the same symbol. :-)

The prototype simply indicates a variable number of arguments. All I can really say is that it's a bit like C's `printf` function, if you happen to know that. The function just keeps pulling in arguments as it needs them.

The `catch (...)` code simply means, catch any exception. (Usually you put this after a number of specific catch blocks, so that this works as a "catch-all".)

Answer (score 3):

For a catch, it means catch anything.  So all exceptions thrown will enter this catch block.

For an argument list, it means a variable number of arguments will be there.  You have to use the stdarg.h API to parse them.

Answer (score 3):

> $5.2.2/6 - "A function can be declared
>   to accept fewer arguments (by
>   declaring default arguments (8.3.6))
>   or more arguments (by using the
>   ellipsis, ... 8.3.5) than the number
>   of parameters in the function
>   definition (8.4). [Note: this implies
>   that, except where the ellipsis (...)
>   is used, a parameter is available for
>   each argument.]"

That pretty well sums up the interepretation of the declaration of "information_log" in OP

> $15.3/6 - "A ... in a handler’s
>   exception-declaration functions
>   similarly to ... in a function
>   parameter declaration; it specifies a
>   match for any exception. If present, a
>   ... handler shall be the last handler
>   for its try block."

Though not a standard term, it is frequently referred to as the catch all clause or catch all handler.

```
void f(){
    try{
        throw 2.2;       // throw double
    }
    catch(int){}              // standard conversion from double to int not permitted
    catch(...){
        cout << "catch it here";   // is caught here in catch all clause
    }
}

int main(){
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ellipsis notation represents variable parameter list.

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhdxye9(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Functions with an Unspecified Number of Parameters](http://www-control.eng.cam.ac.uk/~pcr20/C_Manual/chap06.html)

> Using the ellipsis, ..., with C++
>   function prototypes, ***means that the
>   function can be specified with an
>   unknown number and type of parameters***.
>   This feature can be used to suppress
>   parameter type checking and to allow
>   flexibility in the interface to the
>   function. C++ allows functions be to
>   declared with an unspecified number of
>   arguments.